# fluentd parse log partially json

Tags: json, elasticsearch, syslog, fluentd

I have an source from syslog proto in fluentd, but the line is not fully syslog compliant.

```
142>May 31 16:22:56 haproxy[77]: {"ident":"haproxy","client_ip":"172.20.1.3","c....}
```

I need to parse the json part before submitting it to elasticsearch/kibana.

how would you do that? This is producing me a "failed to parse message data"

```
<source>
  @type syslog
  port 514
  tag haproxy-logs
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
  key_name log
</source>
```

I also tried a standard syslog input, whithout parsing. and a filter whith json parser, but whitout success.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working by doing it in 2 times:

```
<source>
  @type syslog
  port 514
  tag haproxy-logs
  <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /(?<jsonmsg>\{\".*)/
  </parse>
</source>
```

and

```
<filter haproxy-logs**>
  @type parser
  format json
  time_key date_time
  time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S.
  key_name jsonmsg
  reserve_data true
</filter>
```